# My printf function in c isn't printing anything

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting

I have written the code, I want to print trailing spaces followed by my character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() 
{
  for(int i =5;i<=1;i--)
    printf("%*s\n",i,"p");

  return 0;
}
```

The above code is not giving any output.
Can anyone explain what the problem is?

Comment: Try reading out loud what the code does to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (or roommate or similar).

Answer (score 3):

Did you intend to use `i>=1`?  As of now your `for` loop is not running even once.

Thus Change

```
  for (int i = 5; i <= 1; i--){
```

to

```
  for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--){
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop condition is wrong. Change the condition of for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  for(int i =5;i>=1;i--)
    printf("%*s\n",i,"p");

  return 0;
}
```

or,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
    printf("%*s\n",i,"p");

  return 0;
}
```

Happy Coding!